# Input text into SVG2RLG Python Library

Tags: python, css, svg

For a number of reasons, I cannot use a file as SVG input into my SVG2RLG function. In Python, is it possible to convert to PNG with SVG2RLG without using a seperate file?

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
drawing = svg2rlg(tp)
```

Where `tp` is a string, such as the following:

```
tp="""<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="200" height="250" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
  <rect x="60" y="10" rx="10" ry="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

  <circle cx="25" cy="75" r="20" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
  <ellipse cx="75" cy="75" rx="20" ry="5" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

  <line x1="10" x2="50" y1="110" y2="150" stroke="orange" stroke-width="5"/>
  <polyline points="60 110 65 120 70 115 75 130 80 125 85 140 90 135 95 150 100 145"
      stroke="orange" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

  <polygon points="50 160 55 180 70 180 60 190 65 205 50 195 35 205 40 190 30 180 45 180"
      stroke="green" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

  <path d="M20,230 Q40,205 50,230 T90,230" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>"""
```

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614118/python-convert-text-of-svg-to-png-without-cairo ?  If so, you should flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem, but from two different ways. This way is using svglib with text input, my other question is any solution that converts svg to png without Cairo. Should I still flag as duplicate?